# RegistrationActivity.class is showing error cannot resolve symbol: RegistrationActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

in the last line RegistrationActivity.class is showing error cannot resolve symbol: RegistrationActivity in android studio

package com.example.sagacious;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Animation topAnimation, bottomAnimation;
    ImageView sagacious_logos__1_;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        topAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.top_animation);
        bottomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_animation);
        sagacious_logos__1_ = findViewById(R.id.logo);

        sagacious_logos__1_.setAnimation(topAnimation);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Um, import it if it's in another package.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.